# Laravel foreach ajax get HTTP 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

This is my AJAX:

```
    $('#absensi').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var data_kelas = button.data('pkelas');
    var id = button.data('pid');
    var modal = $(this);
    //console.log(id);
    document.getElementById("vkelas").innerHTML = data_kelas;
    $.ajax({
      type : 'get',
      url : '{{URL::route('detail.class')}}',
      data : {'id': id},
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data); //check 
        $('#siswa').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

This is my controller:

```
      $output="";
      $admin = Auth::user()->sekolah_id;
      $murids= Student::where('sekolah_id', $admin)
      ->where('ruang_id', $request->id)
      ->get();
      if ($murids)
      {
        $i=1;
        foreach ($murids as $murid)
        {
          $stu .= '<tr><td>'.$i++.'</td>
                  <td>'.$murid->name.'</td>
                  </tr>';
        }
        return Response($stu); //show on html
      }
```

I got error like this:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/detailclass?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: see logs, what line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 500 means: "Internal Server Error". Which tells you something went wrong server side.

As far as i can tell, $stu is not defined, but that shouldn't throw a 500 error. I think you should change to this, to prevent a notice:

```
$stu='';
$i=1;
foreach ($murids as $murid)
{
    $stu .= '<tr><td>'.$i++.'</td>
        <td>'.$murid->name.'</td>
        </tr>';
}
return Response($stu); //show on html
```

However, for the 500 error I would check the server logs if i were you. They should show you enough information on what went wrong.